# jQuery UI Touch Punch and dynamically loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-touch-punch

jQuery UI Touch Punch works perfectly if content was loaded in DOM before loading this library.
After loading content dynamically into the DOM (like HTML-tags <select> and <input>) these tags are not responding anymore on touch-events. 
(can be simulated in Chrome)
Dragging elements on touch devices is still working fine 

Suggestions are very welcome. Thanks

Comment: can you show a code example of how it's used ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The funny thing is that when I made a simplified example, it just works fine. I cannot reproduce my question.
I will first investigate my own code again and again.